# Как в БД хранить последовательность данных?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, postgresql

Я создаю статьи и категории и хочу, что б статьи отображались внутри категории именно в той последовательности как хочет администратор, а не по алфавиту или дате.
Если просто хранить

```
id | category_id | article_id
```

то такой вариант не подойдёт, либо же добавлять порядковый индекс, но если админ последовательность изменит, то сложно "контролировать ситуацию".
Я подумал о варианте с полями `json`, где бы внутри категории хранился бы массив айдишников статей, и если админ изменил последовательность, то сразу кидает все статьи в нужной последовательности. Так как их не много, то на производительности это не скажется.
Вопрос - кто как реализует подобный функционал?

Comment: А индекс сортировки не подойдет?

Comment: Добавляется поле `sort` или `order`. Сортируется на основе этого поля. Легко редактируется и поддерживается

Comment: Просто не обязательно делать индекс сортировки `int` можно к примеру `char(5)` но использовать цифры, тогда к примеру у Вас '2' будет после '100', а '101' будет после '100' но перед '2' (ну в зависимости от направления сортировки)

Comment: @zakiroof  нет,  последовательность может быть случайной, То-есть админ просто в своём порядке разместить может